# How do I update in google cloud

Tags: cloud, google

resources:

- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: tcp-firewall-rule
  properties:
  network: global/networks/default
  sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  targetTags: ["http","http-server"]
  allowed:

  - IPProtocol: TCP
    ports: ["80", "8080", "3000", "8000"]
- name: cs353c-student-project
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
  zone: europe-west2-c
  machineType: zones/europe-west2-c/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
  tags:
  items: ["http","http-server"]
  disks:

  - deviceName: boot
    type: PERSISTENT
    boot: true
    autoDelete: true
    initializeParams:
    sourceImage: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts
    networkInterfaces:
  - network: global/networks/default
    accessConfigs:

    - name: External NAT
      type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
      networkTier: STANDARD

I have been trying to update the file I am able to create it but once I get to the updating side of things i get this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1701215644724-60b3f2230aeb2-a91db4f0-b755fb22]: errors:

- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/cs353/resources/cs353c-student-project
  message: "{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"404"
  ,"ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"errors":[{"domain":"global","
  message":"The resource 'projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts'
  \ was not found","reason":"notFound"}],"message":"The resource 'projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts'
  \ was not found","statusMessage":"Not Found","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/dishdelight-b0d5d/zones/europe-west2-c/instances"\

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 ceased to be supported by Canonical in May. https://ubuntu.com/blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support You'll need a third-party image or preferably use a more recent version of Ubuntu to avoid security issues.